# Removing focus from a mvc ajax dropdown after using select by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have an AjaxDropDown and I am calling the `onchange` event whenever the dropdown value changes. In the `ajaxstop` function I am binding data to the drop-down and selecting some value. So the focus is currently on dropdown as I am using `select`. Afterwards, whenever I click anywhere on the page the `onchange` event is called. Is there any way to set the focus of that dropdown to false after using select?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ajaxstop(function(){
    var dropDown=$('#ddlDropDown').data('tDropDownList');
    dropDown.select(0);
});
```

Comment: use this `$('#textarea').blur()` after select

Comment: i tried this also but it will remove focus from hidden field but not from ajaxdropdown. can u please suggest me how to remove from ajaxdropdown

Comment: I didnt know that,anyway your ajax drop down is just a element right  then this should work for sure.else you can try setting the focus on the body tag,that should fix it

Comment: how to set focus on the body tag??

Comment: `$('body').focus();` call this statement to set focus to body tag . Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the focus to something else, preferably something useful:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
  $('#target').focus();
});
```